# Costly Immutable Operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I have a data in my redux state that has like ~100,000 json records (with each record having some 8 key value pairs).

I have a logic written on client side to refresh this data every 30 seconds (every 30 seconds I make a call to server to get what records to remove and what records to add).

I do this processing in my reducer function, for this I have written a method "mergeUpdates" that iterates through the state.data object identifies what to remove and what to insert.

I was using `fromJs(state.data).toJs` from immutable to clone the state.data and make an update (state.data is not immutable). But this cloning turned out to be very costly operation (takes around 2 seconds for 100,000 records) hence I removed the cloning and started modifying state.data itself that resulted in "Assignment to function parameter" lint error because I am modifying data that is being passed to a function.

```
initialState = {
  data: {}
}

doSomething(state, change) {
    // iterates on state and updates state
    state = doSomethingElse();
    return state;
}

mergeUpdates(state, change) {
   // some logic
   state = doSomething(state, change)

   // some more logic
   return state;
}


export default function (state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REFRESH: {
            return mergeUpdates(state.data, action.data)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to handle such cases, should I assign state to a new reference in "mergeUpdates" and "doSomething" methods and return a new reference, or make my data inside state an immutable or something else?

For ex: is this considered a good practice?

```
doSomething(state, change) {
    let newState = state; 

    // process change and return newState

    return newState; 
}

mergeUpdates(state, change) {
    let newState = state;

    // apply change on newState 
    newState = doSomething(newState, change);

   // return newState
   return newState;

}
```

Comment: Mm best practise, either: handle processing server side and have small state in frontend or use Mutable state, try Mobx for example, (my preference for react state management)  https://mobx.js.org/

Comment: Thanks but I am already using Redux for state management. So I dont think mobX is required.

Comment: Have you tried [deep-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-clone) npm package? probably faster than cloning to json? Otherwise i'd strongly suggest to not use 100.000 rows in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using Immutable.js's `toJS()` and `fromJS()` functions as much as possible.  Per its author Lee Byron, [this are the most expensive operations in the library](https://twitter.com/leeb/status/746733697093668864).

I would advise finding a different approach.  Some suggestions:

- If your data is already in Immutable.js, use the other functions it provides to help update that data (such as `Map.withMutations()`)
- If that data isn't already in Immutable.js, or you want to avoid using it, you might want to look [one of the many immutable update libraries available](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities), some of which are specifically intended to help merge new values into existing data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Redux itself does not force user to use plain object for state management. You can use immutable object to store data and the only thing you need to do is that re-inits brand new state by fromJS as you did above.
Beside, immutable must be used in entire app. Actually I suggest you use spread operator for data modifying if your data structure is not complicated instead of cumbersome Immutable. (for me, over 3 level down the tree is complicated).